# How to redirect user to the review tab of the app page on Google Play from a browser?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app published on google play.
I want a url that redirects users to the review tab on the app's page on google play!

In the documentation of publishing an app, there is url for redirecting the user to the details tab (default) of the app.
I want when a user clicks the link which i ll publish on some webpages (like "Write a Review"), the landing page shouuld have the review tab opened on the apps page on google play!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a hack that works: append **&reviewId=0** to the end of the URL.

The reviewId parameter allows you to link to a particular review, but if the review is not found, you simply end up in the "User Reviews" tab.

Example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cureatr.messenger&reviewId=0

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not notice that. I was redirecting the users to the first comment. silly of me. Thanks again, this works perfectly!

Comment: Good to hear! I was almost ready to give up when I stumbled upon this hack.

Comment: This hack used to work, but not anymore. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sadly it does not work anymore, I wonder why google removed it.

Comment: Doesn't work on Android 11. There is no option to leave a review in Play Store

Answer (score 2):

Just to update this, I don't think this is possible anymore. It does not say so in the Linking to Google Play documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play

Just redirect to the page of your application, "Rate this App" part is seen right away and user can see the "Write a review" link too.