# Google Play Store link directly to ratings heading

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to create a more streamlined link to rate an app.

From within an android app, it is simple to link to the app page on the play store `market://details?id=<package_name>`  **However**, this links to the top of the app's page, and the user has to scroll down to find the rating control.

Generally, the fewer actions needed, the more likely the user is to follow through. (e.g. If they scroll past the rating control accidentally, they're likely to just go back to whatever they were doing before.)  Therefore, ideally the "Rate on store" button in the app could not only open the appropriate page in the play store, but open it to the correct heading.  The documentation either doesn't list how to do this, or does so in a non obvious location.

There is an old question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991193/how-to-redirect-user-to-the-review-tab-of-the-app-page-on-google-play-from-a-bro) where the accepted answer is to append &reviewId=0 to the market link.  i.e. `market://details?id=<package_name>&reviewId=0`  Unfortunately this method no longer works.

Is there a currently working way to link a user directly to the correct position on the google play store page for rating an app?

Comment: Are you saying that `rateIntentForUrl()` is not working anymore?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720632/325545

Comment: Have you found any link directly to ratings heading?

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: I have noticed that Google docs opens an intent to rate app directly from an activity that emulates a dialog. No visiting the play store required. Anyone find out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Google recently released their new In-App Review API. This enables you to show a rating screen directly in your app.

You can find out how to implement it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review